# Occasional SSL error serving GitHub Pages site over custom domain

Tags: ssl, github-pages

Using GitHub pages built-in SSL, I have been serving a github pages site over https since it was announced. I set this up by following the tutorial GitHub provides. However, perhaps 25% of the time when I try to access the site, I get an SSL error that says the browser cannot find the certificate. Reloading the page one or more times resolves the issue for a while. The site use enforced HTTPS. Due to the intermittent nature of the issue, I have failed to determine the cause. I am unsure of what information I could provide to help diagnose the error.

Edit: the error is NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID on chrome

Comment: What exact error do you get? SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN?

Comment: Definitely a [Github support](https://github.com/contact) issue.